# How can I achieve view-model separation in a Javascript component for editing HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, architecture, reactjs

I need to build an in-browser WYSI(more-or-less)WYG editor for a specific subset of HTML. This requires that the model HTML elements can be decorated with additional markup for editing support. Possibly, some model HTML elements will have to be replaced entirely for the purpose of editing.

I want to avoid transforming back and forth between the editor markup HTML and the output markup HTML because this has proved to be very error-prone in the previous incarnation of the component.

Instead, I want a clean separation of model and view, preferable using one of the client-side MVC frameworks such as React.js.

How can this be achieved? So far, I have come up with the following ideas:

- Represent the model as browser DOM and use this as the model for the views that generate the editor markup (and behaviour)
- Represent the model using React's virtual DOM (is this even possible?)
- Roll my own model representation using Javascript's data types. However, this will require writing a parser and a serializer, which I'd very much like to avoid.

How is this done in other editor components? Is this approach even feasible?

**Edit:** To clarify the use case a bit more, I am not looking for an architecture that supports the usual editing of inline elements like `<strong>`, `<a>` et al. but a combination of in-place-editing of inline elements (I'm considering using something like [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) for this) as well as more structural edits such as cloning `<div>`s and layout `<table>`s and moving them around.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic here. However, you may find better luck [SoftwareRecs.SE](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/tour). Remember to read [their question requirements](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as they are more strict than this site.

Comment: This is off-topic, but not using the browser's DOM because of "cross-browser compatibility and good performance" sounds rather strange. The browser is built around the DOM, anything on top of it is most likely much slower than the native DOM, and it's more likely to add compatibility issues, not reduce them, because now you have an additional layer of compatibility to worry about (the non-browser-DOM library's compatibility with browsers.)

Comment: @Juhana, the browser's DOM is famously slow (which is the entire point behind React's usage of a virtual DOM) due to the API and because it needs to check whether stuff has to be re-rendered. I don't need rendering, I just want to manipulate the model.

Comment: But as long as you don't manipulate elements *in the document* then the browser doesn't do the re-render check. You don't need a library to do that.

Comment: The guideline you're referencing also states that "Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it" - which I think the OP has done. It's a real programming issue, and he's presented the problem (and then went on to suggest possible solutions). If the question had been "what's the best library to fake the DOM?", then sure, the question would have been off topic.

Comment: Would the question be acceptable if I reformulated it as "What is a good approach to achieve View-Model separation in an in-browser component for editing HTML?"

Comment: Would your "model" be the entire content of the WYSIWG editor? If so, then how would you decorate granular parts?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, then that is exactly the question I am asking. How can I use DOM or something isomorphic to it as the model part in MVVM? Basically, I want the ability to update the model (change some attribute, add an element) and have the view updated from this by reflecting those changes as well as maybe rendering additional editor helper markup (selection frames, for example) depending on the element that was added.

Comment: you simply cannot use html for the model if you want to use a contentEditable-based solution. consider something like bbcode or markdown or build form controls that make the adjustments you need to the model based on discrete operations. or just do a lot of validation and blacklist certain problematic browsers. but, you'll never get anything consistent from an editable tag if the browser does the editing.

Answer (score 2):

If I could understand your question correctly, you want to edit several elements in single page?

In such case I would recommend writing this "module" using angularjs directives (wired by attribute so your semantic to html is same as it is not applied at all to document). This directive (when angular app is loaded) should change elements "editable" attribute which would allow user to edit content of element. So lets say template is like this:

`<div id="title-editor" my-editor>...</div>`

it could be scenario when user blur this div it then fires event in directive and sends content to backend.

Here is working directive which could be candidate to review it https://github.com/TerryMooreII/angular-wysiwyg

Bottom line, is that you can have multiple "placeholders" in page, so you define layout and what web parts are placed where in page, other things are in hands of page moderator.

One more note, name each placeholder, so you can identify them on backend and fill data if your case is like that, or you could use jquery/angular to fill them on page load. It is question what is your preferred way :)

On backend side, you could use redis or mongo to store this place holder logical structure rather then trying to represent complete DOM structure and recreate it each time one reads it from backend. So it would be much quicker to load this way.

For parts which you want to drag and drop on page, again you will need some place holders, but this is different kind of "editor" so you would need additional angular directive. Here is one more which could help gaining knowladge on how to. http://codef0rmer.github.io/angular-dragdrop.

Combining this two, you could have something close to what you need. Again. You have to (as developer) be responsible for page layout, since you have to define at least where top level (drag and drop) placeholders are.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, it is not a question of which library to use or which pattern. It is more a role based architecture. Lets say one of the elements you can create and edit in your editor is a `<strong>` tag. The end users will see

```
<strong class="some-class">Some content</strong>
```

While your editors will see the same element (hence WYSIWYG) but with additional styles or controls, lets say it will appear red and have a 'remove' button.

```
<strong class="some-class">Some content <sup>Remove</sup></strong>
```

We can leverage CSS to achieve these differences regarding the visual aspect of the elements just by using an additional class on the editor canvas.

```
.canvas strong{
    font-weight: bold;
}
.canvas strong sup{
    display:none;
}

.editing.canvas strong{
    color:red;
}
.editing.canvas strong sup{
    display:inline;
}

// your end users will see
<div class="canvas">
    // but the <sup> element will be display:none; by default
    <strong class="some-class">Some content <sup>Remove</sup></strong>
</div>

// your editors will see
<div class="canvas editing">
    // here, the 'editing' class will make the <sup> visible and change the color to red
    <strong class="some-class">Some content <sup>Remove</sup></strong>
</div>
```

Granted, this is a reeeally simple example but you can see how more complex elements fit into this architecture. Now for the js part.

Lets say that our strong element will throw an alert for our end users on hover, and for our editors it will handle clicks on the 'remove' element.

```
function StrongElement(){
    var id,
        el,
        data = {
           content: 'default content',
           classname: 'default classname'
        };

    function setId(id){
        id = id;
        render();
    }

    function setContent(content){
        data.content = content;
        render();
    }

    (function create(){
        // this is done only once!
        el = document.createElement('strong'); // this in more complex elements would be a template
        var remove = document.createElement('sup');
        remove.innerHTML = 'remove';
        el.appendChild(remove);
    })();

    function render(){
        el.id = id;
        el.className = data.classname;
        el.innerHTML = data.content;
        return el;
    }

    function onHover(){
        alert('Im strong and I like it');
    }

    function remove(){
        // more on editor later*
        if (editor.isInEditingMode()){
            editor.remove(id);
        }
    }

    // expose the public methods
    return {
        render: render
    };
}
```

We have defined a js 'class' to handle any interaction of this element. It can be way more complex and the element could have nested elements. What's additional to a common html plugin is that these elements have an id, and some methods will only work if the variable `editor` exists. Lets take a look at the editor:

```
function Editor(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'), // note that the canvas can be a text area, a div, or even a html5 canvas where your elements are rendered graphically instead of the DOM
        elements = [],
        editingMode = true;

    function addElement(element){
        // keep track of the js instance of the element
        elements.push(element);
        // give it an id that both the element and the editor know
        element.setId(elements.length);
        // append the graphic representation of the instance (some html tags) into the graphic representation of the editor
        canvas.appendChild(element.render());
        // we return the id so that anyone who added an element can keep track of it
        return elements.length; // the id, will be the index in the array of elements
    }

    function removeElement(id){
        // this could be way better but its just for demo purposes
        elements[id] = null;
    }

    function refresh(){
        // elements are already in the canvas, so we iterate over all of them 
        for (var i in elements){
            // and re render them
            elements[i].render();
        }
    }

    function setEditingMode(mode){
        editingMode = mode;
        if (editingMode){
             canvas.className = 'editing';
        }else{
             canvas.className = '';
        }
    }

    function isInEditingMode(){
        return editingMode;
    }

    return {
        isInEditingMode: isInEditingMode,
        addElement: addElement,
        removeElement: removeElement,
        refresh: refresh
    }
}
```

This is a very simple editor, to get this to a production ready level you'll need to deal with positions of each element, in this case we could assume elements are shown in the same order as they were added. But this gets more interesting when representing a tree structure or x, y and z positions for elements drawn on a pixel canvas. That position data would be added to each element and the render function in each should be able to handle it with reference to the parent editor.

This uber simple editor would work something like this:

```
<div id="canvas"></div>

var editor = new Editor(),
    element = new Strong();

element.setContent("I'm Stronger");
editor.addElement( element );
editor.refresh();
editor.setEditingMode(true); // this should add the 'editing' class and you should now see the remove button and red colored content
editor.setEditingMode(false); // this should return the element to a end user state and if you hover you should get an alert
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pzef52gh/1/

Basically the way I'd go is design and implement the elements for the end user, including styles and functionality. After that, I'd build on top of those elements the additional styles and functionality for when you are in edit mode. You can do this in any language and any framework. The example might seem familiar for backbonejs users but if I had to do something like this today, I'd use angular and each 'element' would be a directive with a editing/non-editing state. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer. Unfortunately, this approach means I will have extra editor support elements in the edited HTML, which is what I'm trying to avoid (and which I have stated above). I cannot have any extra editor elements in the HTML that is saved to the database by the editor component.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into a Flux implementation with ReactJS. With that, your models can easily be abstracted to services called with Flux actions, which in turn can be listened to with stores where your in-app data can be mutated. That way, your view logic is in the components, but your business logic is abstracted elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, I feel it is too generic. How exactly would I go about applying this to my specific use case? How can Flux help me deal with a model that is DOM itself?

Comment: I believe this is your what you looking for. Pick a library that implements the flux architecture to model the data you are using in your views. When you want to manipulate the data... call it's action.

Comment: @cwbutler probably yes, and in fact I am working in this direction right now, but I am looking for guidance that is more specific to my situation and the concrete issues I have raised.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use external tools, and make your own. More control, less useless code.

MVC : model is the edited data, view is the html displayed, controller is the SQL I/O and save/edit features.

What is the problem with that ?

Be methodic, clear and *less is more* oriented, you ll succeed in. And master it to all extents.

Comment: The problem is that the Model is DOM too, and I really have trouble wrapping my head around how this is going to work in the context of MVC, since DOM is highly hierarchic and non-observable. Could you elaborate on how to solve this?

Comment: I'm not sure what's your issue exactly. Maybe I'm too easy, but editing HTML is both editing code (a long text), and rendering preview ("run" the code in a $myframe.html(mylongtext) ). Said very quickly. What is your problem ? You know it os difficult to express difficulties when one has the head in the problem, zoom out and explain simply, be synthetic. Thanks

Comment: So, in this case I'm not only rendering a preview but an interactive preview. There should be selection frames, hover buttons on divs and stuff like that. This means that the editor view is different from the actual HTML code that I want to edit. Which means I'll have a view transform f(mylongtext), to borrow your example. If I now change the model very quickly (think range slider changing some numeric attribute like color or border-radius), re-rendering the view continuously is guaranteed to wreck performance. That's the problem I'm thinking about.

Comment: Ok. Clearer, thanks. You wont get great perf, for sure. Beautiful proj, I cannot help sorry. I must say it s not a matter of MVC at all, to me. Very no. OF course MVC can improve it all, but it is more about design/conception. Exactly out of StackOverflow aim, not a code matter but architecture. **off-topic**

Comment: Architecture is code, at least to me. But thanks for pushing me on clarifying the problem, this has already helped a lot.

Comment: "Arch is code": I think and said the same, until I fed up with seeing my questions minus-ed. Take care. I'm sure there is a StackExchange site for code design&architecure.